# For $V = \min(X, Y)$, calculating the CDF, is it $\mathbb{P}(V \leq k)$ or $\mathbb{P}(V \geq k)$

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have this variable $V = \min(X, Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables geometrically distributed and independent. I want to compute the CDF. My attempt:

Let $k \in V(\Omega) = \mathbf{N}^*$.
We have
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}(V \leq k)
  &= \mathbb{P}(\min(X,Y) \leq k) \\
  &= 1 - \mathbb{P}(\min(X,Y) > k) \\
  &= 1 - \mathbb{P}(X > k, Y > k) \\
  &= 1 - \mathbb{P}(X > k) \times P(Y > k) \\
  &= 1 - \mathbb{P}(X > k)^2 \\
  &= 1 - (1 - p)^{2k}
\end{align*}
because $\mathbb{P}(X > k) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \leq k) = (1-p)^k$.

Is this correct? The solution given by the teacher was not this, and I feel this is right, as I want to get the PDF from the CDF as
$$
  \mathbb{P}(V = k)
  = \mathbb{P}(V \leq k) - \mathbb{P}(V \leq k - 1)
  = (1- p)^{2k - 2} - (1-p)^{2k} \,.
$$
Please be as clear as possible.

Comment: Where does your solution differ from the teacher's?

Comment: In the solution of the $CDF$ he has $P(V \leq k) = (1-p)^{2k}$ I think he just missed the $1 - $ part?

Comment: I think your solution is correct. One sanity check to convince yourself that the teacher's solution is incorrect: $P(V \le k)$ has to be an increasing function in $k$.

Comment: Yes, that s a very known $CDF$ check

Comment: @user1125632 A more comfortable sanity check is $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \mathbb P(V\leq k)=1$ Which one of the two solutions fulfill this condition?